# Чтение файла C++

Tags: c++builder, c++

Как сделать так, чтобы проект увидел мой файл, не прописывая полный путь. Input.txt лежит в одной папке с проектом, однако его не находит. Компилятор gcc

```
ifstream input("input.txt", ifstream::in);
    if (input.fail())
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't open a file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: А если указать таки полный путь, работает?

Comment: да, работает

Comment: Тогда попробуйте вывести текущий каталог (`getcwd`). Могу поспорить, что ваш текущий каталог не совпадает с тем, где находится проект.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы программа увидела файл, без указания пути, нужно, чтобы файл лежал в рабочей папке программы, а это обычно, та папка, где и программа.

Comment: Заблуждаетесь. На этапе отладки (когда запуск осуществляется из IDE), например, программа находится в проекте в субдиректориях (зависит от IDE). А файл "без указания пути" должен лежать в корне проекта. А вот если запустить отдельно (не из IDE) программу, тогда для Win именно так и будет - файл должен быть в той же папке, что и программа. Но вот под Lin я не уверен, что это условие будет соблюдаться всегда. А топикастер спрашивает про случай именно с проектом, а не с программой.